# onGlobalLayoutListener vs postRunnable

Tags: android, view, lazy-loading, runnable

I am trying to do calculate view's x,y positions after completion of loading of activity. What I did is `view.postDelayed(runnable, 2000)` which is working fine. code reviewer is not happy with this and suggested to use OnGlobalLayoutListener to know about the completion of activity loading. Somehow I don't like OnGlobalLayoutListener because it is associated with entire view tree which is not required for my solution. I am trying to understand pros and cons of these approaches. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If all you are trying to do is read the view's `x` and `y` coordinates, I recommend using `view.post(Runnable)` with no delay (unless there is a good reason to include a delay). This will add the `Runnable` to a message queue to in the UI thread. The `Runnable` will wait to execute until after your `View` is inflated and attached to the window. Since `View` position property values depend on the view's layout context, posting a `Runnable` will give you the timing that you are looking for.

As you mentioned in your question description, an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` will apply to the entire `View`'s layout as the class name suggests. An `OnGlobalLayoutListener` should only be considered if you are concerned with the layout state or visibility of any or all views within the view tree. I.e. anything that causes the view tree to be re-laid out.

Comment: Ryan thanks for your reply. I like view.post(Runnable) but only concern, is  it guaranteed to execute the runnable only after view is completely drawn ? My goal is to calculate the screen dimensions along with view's x,y. So I introduced an arbitrary 2sec delay.

Comment: @Blanc I've always been able to rely on the `Runnable` waiting to run until the view's drawing has completed. I've never need to add an arbitrary delay to the execution.

Comment: yeah I tried that w/o delay. Seems working fine. I am looking for any official documentation from android develop to support this. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Code reviewer is not happy because you wait 2s and guess that the loading of the activity is finished by then. This may be the case with your emulator or device but on older and slower devices the activity may not have finished loading. To be 100% safe that the activity has finished loading you should use the listener to inform the 'listener' when loading is completed.

Comment: Micha F - forget about code reviewer happiness. I am looking for better implementation onGlobalLayoutListener vs Runnable on posted to main thread. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct way of doing this is by adding an onPreDrawListener to the view. This is the listener that is called when the view is about to be drawn, and where you already have all the information about it's size (width and height) and position (X and Y).

Example:

```
final View v = new View(getContext());
        v.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                float myX = v.getX();
                float myY = v.getY();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Don't forget to make the method onPreDraw return true, I don't know why but Android Studio makes it return false when you create the listener.
Also don't forget to remove the listener from the view, otherwise it might be uselessly called again.